# Andorid Here Maps : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR),

Tags: android, heremaps

I have two problems with here android SDK 3.14

1.Periodically this error appears after map inicialization and only removing installed maps helps.

```
 E/MAPSERVICE: c3eexxxxxxxxxx
 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 26380 (xxxxxxxxxx), pid 26196 (xxxxxxxxxx)
 *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
 Build fingerprint: 'POINTMOBILE/pm90/pm90:9/PKQ1.190528.001/R26:user/release-keys'
 Revision: '0'
 ABI: 'arm64'
 pid: 26196, tid: 26380, name: ocash.xxxxxxxxxx  >>> xxxxxxxxxx <<<
 signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
 Cause: null pointer dereference
     x0  000000000000000b  x1  0000000000000000  x2  0000007bceddbefc  x3  0000007bc9b00a80
     x4  0000007bc9b00c60  x5  0000000000000004  x6  0000000000002b9b  x7  0000000000002b9b
     x8  0000000000000004  x9  00000000fffffff0  x10 0000000000000006  x11 0000000000000002
     x12 00000000edcb868c  x13 0000007bdd595ec4  x14 0000000000000000  x15 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
     x16 0000007c67f5abd0  x17 0000007c67edd824  x18 0000007bcebbb9a0  x19 0000007bcedbc208
     x20 0000007bc9b00a80  x21 0000007bc9b00c60  x22 0000007bceddbe90  x23 0000007bc9b00fb0
     x24 0000007bceddbec0  x25 0000007bceddbee8  x26 0000000000000006  x27 0000000000000000
     x28 0000000000000020  x29 0000007bc9b00a70
     sp  0000007bc9b00a10  lr  0000007bccd4f6d8  pc  0000007bccd4f6f8
 backtrace:
     #00 pc 0000000000e496f8  /data/app/xxxxxxxxxx-yZ_P2WwbF_YmpVEMFSQ0bw==/lib/arm64/libMAPSJNI.so
     #01 pc 0000000000e4bafc  /data/app/xxxxxxxxxx-yZ_P2WwbF_YmpVEMFSQ0bw==/lib/arm64/libMAPSJNI.so
     #02 pc 0000000000e2b9e4  /data/app/xxxxxxxxxx-yZ_P2WwbF_YmpVEMFSQ0bw==/lib/arm64/libMAPSJNI.so
     #03 pc 0000000000e2a50c  /data/app/xxxxxxxxxx-yZ_P2WwbF_YmpVEMFSQ0bw==/lib/arm64/libMAPSJNI.so
     #04 pc 0000000000e8adfc  /data/app/xxxxxxxxxx-yZ_P2WwbF_YmpVEMFSQ0bw==/lib/arm64/libMAPSJNI.so
     #05 pc 0000000000e8a08c  /data/app/xxxxxxxxxx-yZ_P2WwbF_YmpVEMFSQ0bw==/lib/arm64/libMAPSJNI.so
     #06 pc 0000000000df18f4  /data/app/xxxxxxxxxx-yZ_P2WwbF_YmpVEMFSQ0bw==/lib/arm64/libMAPSJNI.so
     #07 pc 0000000000df1408  /data/app/xxxxxxxxxx-yZ_P2WwbF_YmpVEMFSQ0bw==/lib/arm64/libMAPSJNI.so
     #08 pc 00000000000c1668  /data/app/xxxxxxxxxx-yZ_P2WwbF_YmpVEMFSQ0bw==/lib/arm64/libgnustl_shared.so (execute_native_thread_routine+32)
     #09 pc 0000000000092038  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
     #10 pc 0000000000023968  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

2. The error occurs when in the application after calculating the route for several points (waypoints) we put it on the map. The MapView control displays a view of the entire route and after a few seconds the application crashes. In this case removing installed maps helps too.

[image]

Does anyone know why such errors may appear and why deleting downloaded maps helps? Can maps somehow get damaged during the download?